# Wierd site output

Tags: plugins, php, html

I'm quite new to Wordpress, I've build a website and found out in the Google WebMaster tool that one of the most present keyword was `[%%LINKS%%]`...

I've found this code:

```
<div style="display:none">[%%LINKS%%]</div>
```

I've browse the whole database and the files on my server, I can't find any trace of the line (using `grep -rn "LINKS" .`).

Here's my set up:

- wordpress 4.4;
- Contact Form 7;
- Envato WordPress Toolkit;
- BeTheme;
- Force Regenerate Thumbnails;
- Google XML Sitemaps;
- Slider Revolution;
- W3 Total Cache;

Where should I dig next to solve my problem?

Here's [the source](http://pastebin.com/Pf4iGJyW)

And the output foom r-debug:

```
>>>>>   wp_footer
10      wpcf7_recaptcha_callback_script
        wp_func_jquery
        RevSliderFront::load_icon_fonts
        RevSliderFront::putAdminBarMenus
20      wp_print_footer_scripts
100     mfn_google_remarketing
        mfn_scripts_custom
1000    wp_admin_bar_render
```

Comment: Examine your website's folder. Check for some additional files. It could be that your website is hacked.

Comment: @denis.stoyanov I've downloaded the whole folder and found no trace of `%%LINKS%%` do you have any recommendation? The website is working as it should - beside this thing.

Comment: Well it is not necessary to have an exact match. The whole thing could be encrypted or spliced from some bigger string (even exif data added to an image). Compare your wp-includes, wp-admin, plugins and theme folders whether they are matching the original repositories.

Comment: Could you paste your Website source code to pastebin? There might be a clue where you could look.

Comment: smart malware writers hide their code in the DB if they can. You site was probably hacked or you have a malware on the server, and hacked sites are off-topic.

Comment: This could as well be a JavaScript injecting into the DOM. Sorry, but recovering from hacks (and other localized issues) are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a hack, probably in W3TC.

Try disabling all the Plugins one by one, and if it doesn't go away, try switching to the default theme.

If that did not work, install WordPress from scratch, and transfer the database to it.

If you prefer another debug mode, I suppose your script gets hooked into WordPress in the `wp_footer` action. To verify that, you could comment the line `wp_footer();` out, probably in `footer.php`.
It should be gone with that.

To find out what injected it, try out @rarst [R Debug](https://gist.github.com/Rarst/1739714), which helps you see what action get performed where.

Good luck!

Comment: That is effectively the `wp_footer()` which is causing trouble... Do you have any tutorial on how to use R Degug?

Comment: Upload the File into your Plugins and activate it. Create a new Class `$debug = new R_Debug();`, and list your hooks on `wp_footer`: `$debug->list_hooks( 'wp_footer' );`

Comment: I did, I then examine carefully the functions called and didn't find trace of the culprit...

Comment: Please do the same deactivating the Plugins one by one - when it is gone, you got the bad guy.

Answer (score 0):

`[%%LINKS%%]`is very suspicious. It's inside a `display:none` div, so any links output by a function will be in page source for SEO purposes, but won't display on the site.

You probably did get hacked. Try using [Adminer « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminer/) to search the database for that string.

If you find it, carefully follow https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Support](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Support](https://wordpress.org/support/article/brute-force-attacks/)

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find the string in the database...